# DBT {materialized = "view"} creates a table in the database

Tags: view, dbt, materialized

Trying to understand DBT Materialization strategies -
Some of our models are using the {materialized = "view"} option, and still I see that an underlying table is created in the database (We are using AWS Redshift)

[Documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations) says that:
"When using the **view materialization**, your model is **rebuilt as a view** on each run, via a create view as statement.."
And that:
"When using the **table materialization**, your model is **rebuilt as a table** on each run, via a create table as statement"

Still I see a table with the name of the model under "Tables" and no such view under "Views".

Can someone please explain this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you applying the view configuration?

Comment: Did you start with the "table" materialization, and later switched to view? If so, dbt doesn't drop previously created objects, you have to drop it manually.

Comment: @AleixCC - The configuration is part of the "config" section of the model itself:

{{ config(materialized='view') }}

SELECT
    col_a, ...

Comment: @Limonka - Interesting. I do not this this is the case, but I arrived to a pre-existing infrastructure, so do not know for sure. I think they have been just using the default, which is "view". Thanks!